# Jquery UI Tooltip - Passing parameters into Content

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am trying to use dynamically generated content for a series of tooltips on a page.

The tooltip `triggers` and `targets` are generated by a CMS, with the `triggers` placed inline and the `targets` (which contain the HTML content I wish to display as the tooltip) are inside a hidden div at the foot of the page.

I use a pair of data tags (`data-referencenumberlinks` and `data-referencenumbertargets`) to identify each trigger and target relationship, and I run each type through an index to generate unique numerical references for the pairs.

So far so good.  I cannot figure out how to pass the index number from the trigger (`data-referencenumberlinks`) into the content: option of the tooltip function (you'll see I'm using a var called `thisContent` (currently hard-coded as "1") in the example.

I have tried setting thisContent to:

```
$(this).attr('data-referencenumberlinks', index);
```

and various versions of this but without success - can any body advise how I should create a variable that contains the `data-referencenumberlinks` of the active tooltip and allows tooltip to display the corresponding `data-referencenumbertargets`?

Thanks.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.tooltipFramework').each(function (i, obj) {
        index = $('.tooltipFramework').index(this);
        $(this).attr('data-referencenumbertargets', index);
    });

    $('.tooltipTrigger').each(function (i, obj) {
        index = $('.tooltipTrigger').index(this);
        $(this).attr('data-referencenumberlinks', index);
    });    
    var thisContent = 1;
    $('.tooltipTrigger').tooltip({        
        content: $('[data-referencenumbertargets="' + thisContent + '"]')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ah - typical spend days trying for a fix, ask the experts at stackoverflow, then realise how to solve it yourself minutes later!

for reference, I used this approach:

```
 $('.tooltipTrigger').each(function (i, obj) {
    index = $('.tooltipTrigger').index(this);
    $(this).attr('data-referencenumberlinks', index);
    console.log('index is ' + index);
    $(this).tooltip({ content: $('[data-referencenumbertargets="' + index + '"]') });
});
```

effectively running the tooltip against each element during the index phase -

```
$(this).tooltip({ content: $('[data-referencenumbertargets="' + index + '"]') });
```

Thanks anyway guys.